# WordPress ACF adding into jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to make a background slider, and found the following which works great!

```
<script>
var images=new Array();
images[0]='/images/introimg.png';
images[1]='http://s27.postimg.org/y6tl17eb7/velocita.jpg';
var nextimage=0;
doSlideshow();
function doSlideshow(){
    if(nextimage>=images.length){nextimage=0;}
    $('.homepagesector')
    .css('background-image','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")')
    .fadeIn(500,function(){
        setTimeout(doSlideshow,4000);
    });
}
</script>
```

But my issue is as follows - where I have /images/introimg.png, this does not work. What I would like, is to be able to make this image editable in the CMS, using advanced custom fields. IS there a simple way to do this and add it to my current code, or a workaround?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, is there a way, using this script, to make the backgrounds fade in?
I know this is a seperate question, but thought id ask.

Comment: If anyone has another way this can be done, IE a way to get the image background as a slider within the CMS, that'd also be great